# regex list and count string occurrences

Tags: regex

I am attempting to list and count occurrences in a text file based on a pattern match.  The text file appears to be a syslog, and is composed of a variable record layout. The only tools at my disposal are UltraEdit and TextPad. My objective is matching 4 characters that I define and enter. If the 4 characters match, I also want to include/display x number of characters beyond the match; and, aggregate if possible using regex for UltraEdit or TextPad.

Thank you,
Greg Johnson

Comment: you forgot to post the code that you have already tried.

Comment: Also give an example text, example search input and what the match should be in that example. "matching 4 characters" is ambiguous.

Comment: I've taken several runs at code copied and pasted from websites, but lack of familiarity with the tools is a consideration.

Comment: An example of the desired search pattern text would be "serv" (short for server)   I would like the search return to show "serv0000000001", "serv0000000002", "serv0000000003", and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions provided in UltraEdit user-to-user forums like:

- [Find strings with a regular expression and output them to new file](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=12866)
- [Find numbers in huge file and output them to files line by line](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=15934)
- [Search string and copy all found lines/strings to clipboard or new file](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=876)
- [Equivalent to egrep? (Extract lines from big files)](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=2705)
- and many more

The UltraEdit, Unix or Perl regular expression search string for your example would be `serv[0-9]+`.

It is also possible to

- open your log file in UltraEdit,
- open **Find** dialog,
- enter `serv[0-9]+` as search string,
- enable the *Regular expressions* option (engine does not matter for this search expression),
- enable the *Filter lines* option and select option *Show* and click on button **Next**
  respectively click on button **Show Lines** depending on used version of UltraEdit.

This action results in hiding all lines of the log file not containing the string `serv` with 1 or more digits and showing only the remaining lines containing at least one of the search strings.

It is also possible to use the UltraEdit find option *List lines containing string* to get all lines with at least 1 string found by the expression printed into a separate window.

And last but not least it is also possible to run in UltraEdit a **Find in Files** with the regular expression search string `serv[0-9]+` on the log file only or even multiple files in one or even more directories for getting all lines containing a found string written to output window of UltraEdit or a new text file for further processing like deleting everything than the strings of interest.